# What does it mean by an AC of Infinite frequency?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, frequency

For an AC of infinite frequency, Time period= 1/frequency = 1/$\infty\ $ = 0

So, this means the polarity of AC is '**reversed in every 0 seconds**'? Can you clarify this **phrase**?

Comment: Not really sure how an infinite frequency would make any physical sense

Comment: What aspect of the statement would you like the community to clarify?

Comment: Where have you seen this? This must have not been any example from reality.

Comment: My textbook says that for f=0 , the current is DC i.e.in this circuit reactance of capacitor is infinity and that of the inductor is 0.It got me thinking where is the reverse possible-I thought of when f= $\infty\ $

Comment: Having a voltage and current means that electrons are moving through a wire. With DC they move in one direction; with AC they reverse at whatever time period the AC has. However think about infinite frequency: at T0 they start moving at one way. At T1 they reverse and move the other. However with time period of zero T0 = T1. The result of that can only be that the electrons don't move at all, and there is no current or voltage.